Woocommerce php adding attributes on a global scope for my products
creating variable product with attributes on a global scope. all the attributes are available for each product with variations but not reflecting in the global space of products -> attributes.
The issue is when I'm adding products dynamically the attributes are not resulting as expected to the global setting and i have to manually click each settings for product.
/* $product = "product set from other source";
$colours=['red','green','blue','white'];
*/

$attribute = new WC_Product_Attribute();

$attribute_id = wc_attribute_taxonomy_id_by_name( 'colour' ); // ?
$attribute_id = ? // 0 for local product

$attribute->set_id($attribute_id );
$attribute->set_name( 'Colours' ); 
$attribute->set_options( $colours );
$attribute->set_position( 0 );
$attribute->set_visible( 1 );
$attribute->set_variation( 1 );
$product->set_attributes(array($attribute));
$id = $product->save();

$variation = new WC_Product_Variation();
$variation->set_parent_id($id);
$variation->set_regular_price($price);
$variation->set_attributes($colours);
$variation->save(); 

Result below as expected. not sure if values meant to be buttons or text?

Global Attributes not showing so there is not a linkage.

Attributes are not added globally? if i was to add attributes through WordPress they would not relate/ link to those that are on each variable product.

To use Global attributes, you need first to add them globally with all the related terms for it, in the backend. Then in your code (for a variable product), you will need to set the taxonomy for that attribute and an array of desired existing term Ids as options (not term slugs), like in this answer thread.
